# Unable to join "sys.executable" path with another file

Tags: python

I want to create a file in the python interpreter location.
Here's what I'm doing -

```py
import os
import sys
mainPath = os.path.split(sys.executable)[0]
suffix = '/settings.json'
newPath = os.path.join(mainPath, suffix)
```

My expected output is -

```
newPath = '/usr/python/bin/settings.json'
```

but what I get is

```
newPath = '/settings.json'
```

Is this a privileges issue?

Comment: Use `suffix = 'settings.json'` without the leading slash.

Comment: That fixed it !